# How do you pre-load a form in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that contains lots of stuff, including textboxes, images, panels, and a database. The problem is that when I started running it, the window shows up, but the contents display a few seconds after the window is displayed.

I tried removing this important code in the form's shown event. It is a bit useful, but the program doesn't work properly:

```
Private Sub Inventory_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Label1.Parent = PictureBox1
    Label2.Parent = PictureBox1
    OpenConnection()
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from inventory order by [Item No] asc", conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "inventory")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("inventory")
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    conn.Close()
    If DataGridView1.RowCount <> 0 Then
        PictureBox1.Visible = False
        Label1.Visible = False
        Label2.Visible = False
    End If
    TextBox2.Focus()
    MG.Visible = True
    btnClear.PerformClick()
    txtItemNo.ReadOnly = False
    txtItemNo.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount + 1
    txtItemNo.ReadOnly = True
    btnDelete.Enabled = False
    clearExpiryDate.Visible = False
End Sub
```

How can I fix this delay?

Comment: How much of the above code did you remove? And how do you mean the program doesn't work properly. I probably would put your database initialization and loading your DataSet in your constructor. That way it is preloaded before you try to show your form.

Comment: I removed all of the code above, causing the program not to perform certain tasks needed when the form is shown.

Comment: Looks like all that code could be moved out of the event entirely, and into something like an initialise method that would end with a Me.show. But the time delay while all that database stuff will still have to occur at some point - but at least doing the above will mean that the user sees the wait cursor for a moment then the form opening at a snap, instead of that ghost outline effect.

Comment: @peterG I'm a bit new to this stuff. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Which part is the major bottleneck, the `DataGridView` binding of rows? How many rows are being shown in the grid?

Comment: Probably the `select * from table`, over a network, with no where clause.

Comment: Well, the DataGridView used to have hundreds of rows. But I deleted them to know if it's the one that causes the delay. The ghost effect still persists though.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - agree that `select * from table` is most likely the problem, just hoping the OP can tell us if it 100, 1000 or 10,000 records.

Comment: Create a new sub in your form code and call it 'Initialise' or similar. Cut n paste all your code above into the sub. Then add 'Me.Show' or 'Me.ShowDialog' at the end. Then instead of calling f.show to show the form, call f.initialise. Oh yeah, also put a WHERE clause into your SQL so that you're not pulling the entire table, if you can, as per the other comments

Comment: I can't put a where clause. I was told to make the program preview all records in that database.